# Filtro com paginação - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paginação

Boa noite,

O filtro em si aparece certo, mas ao ir para outra página (pela paginação), perde esse filtro.

Não consigo encontrar o problema, alguém pode me ajudar?

Minha rota:

```
Route::any('/recentes-pesquisa','ActionsRecentsController@recentes')->name('recentes.pesquisa');
```

Controller

```
 $dataForm = $request->except('_token');           
    if (isset($dataForm['num'])){
            $buscaNotas = DB::table('notas')->join('status_notas', 'notas.cd_nota', '=', 'status_notas.cd_nota')->join('prestador','notas.cd_prestador','=','prestador.cd_prestador')->join('competencia','notas.comp_nota','=','competencia.cd_competencia')->select('notas.*', 'status_notas.*','prestador.*','competencia.*')
        ->where('notas.nro_nota', '=', $dataForm['num'])->paginate(10); 
        }
        elseif((isset($dataForm['num'])and ($dataForm['prestador']))){
         $buscaNotas = DB::table('notas')->join('status_notas', 'notas.cd_nota', '=', 'status_notas.cd_nota')->join('prestador','notas.cd_prestador','=','prestador.cd_prestador')->join('competencia','notas.comp_nota','=','competencia.cd_competencia')->select('notas.*', 'status_notas.*','prestador.*','competencia.*')
        ->where('notas.nro_nota', '=', $dataForm['num']) 
        ->where('prestador.nm_prestador','like UPPER',$dataForm['prestador'])->paginate(10);     
        }elseif(isset($dataForm['data_emissao'])){
         $buscaNotas = DB::table('notas')->join('status_notas', 'notas.cd_nota', '=', 'status_notas.cd_nota')->join('prestador','notas.cd_prestador','=','prestador.cd_prestador')->join('competencia','notas.comp_nota','=','competencia.cd_competencia')->select('notas.*', 'status_notas.*','prestador.*','competencia.*')   
        ->whereBetween('notas.dt_emissao_nota',[$dataForm['data_emissao'],$dataForm['data_emissao']])->paginate(10);    
        }


     else{    //se n selecionou nenhum filtro... 
     $buscaNotas = DB::table('notas')
        ->join('status_notas', 'notas.cd_nota', '=', 'status_notas.cd_nota')
        ->join('prestador','notas.cd_prestador','=','prestador.cd_prestador')
        ->join('competencia','notas.comp_nota','=','competencia.cd_competencia')
        ->select('notas.*', 'status_notas.*','prestador.*','competencia.*')
        ->where('notas.comp_nota', '=', 1)
        ->paginate(10);
     }

      return view('\recent')->with('notas_recentes', $buscaNotas)
                            ->with('dataForm',$dataForm);
```

View:

```
  {{ $notas_recentes->appends(['dataForm' => $dataForm])->links() }}
```

---

A URL fica assim:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/recentes-pesquisa?_token=I0BG4fXmLi10U2bfUM6zztwvbUI3oobHOAFYKUtQ&num=&data_emissao=2018-08-12&comp=&prestador=&status=

Ao clicar na segunda pagina, ele fica assim: http://127.0.0.1:8000/recentes-pesquisa?dataForm%5Bdata_emissao%5D=2018-08-12&page=2

Answer (score 3):

Resolvi meu problema trocando na minha view:

```
  {{ $notas_recentes->appends(['dataForm' => $dataForm])->links() }}
```

Para:

```
{{ $notas_recentes->appends($dataForm)->links() }}
```